# deterministic mapping of ids to arbitrary amount of workers

Tags: python

I'm mapping string based ids to 16 workers. The workers have their own ids based on a hex digit, so 0 to f. The mapping uses the first character of a md5 in printable format (hexdigest)

I'd like to make the number of workers arbitrary instead of being forced to use 16 workers. So I need a hashing function to map ids to the workers deterministically.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but how do you guarantee that the first character of the md5 is unique for all 16 workers?

Comment: use the hexdigest format of a md5. It's printable, e.g. 2424d1d1a665402b7c7cf80abef21dd0. Every character is a hex digit so that limits it to the characters 0-9 and a-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transform the hex string into an `int` and use a modulo division to get the correct worker:

```
import struct
import hashlib
number_of_workers = 16
my_md5 = hashlib.md5('stackoverflow.com').hexdigest()
# my_md5 is 'd0cc85b26f2ceb8714b978e07def4f6e'

id = struct.unpack('>L', my_md5.decode('hex')[:4])[0]
# id is 3503064498L
# id % number_of_workers = 2
string_id = '%X' % (id % number_of_workers, )
# string_id = '2'

send_to_worker(string_id, task)
```

I take the first 4 bytes of the md5 and interpret them as an integer. I then use a modulo division to make sure I stay in range of the worker ids, and then transform it back into a string to turn it into the ID.